# Setting ANOTHER app's theme?

Tags: android

Would it be possible to tell the system to load an arbitrary app forcing a different theme? Root is okay.

Comment: Not possible unless you build your own custom rom.

Comment: What is it that would allow it to be done?

Comment: You would need to hack about the entire Android framework to make it happen. That's something Android was not designed to do. Adding that functionality requires a lot of work.

Comment: What about the manifest? Is there a way to modify an app's manifest at or before runtime?

Comment: At runtime no chance. Before maybe - I guess you would need to unpack the apk, then modify the manifest and pack it again. Could work.

Comment: Like what those APK Toolkits do? Is there an aapt port for Android?

Comment: yep, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui build apks while running on Android. No Idea how. Probably building aapt for ARM. Or maybe you can get http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/ to work on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its simply not possible. You can't control the behavior of other apps.

Comment: Don't confuse root with this. It is the default behavior of VM which doesn't allow you to mess up with other apps by creating separate sandboxes for each app. Now if you design/customize your own Android VM then anything is possible. But then the question is, does it worth the fuss? :)